# Toast message reappears after fadeout

Tags: css

I found this toast/snackbar example on w3schools.com and I tried to change it a little bit for my needs but after fading out, it reappears again. Anyone could help me figure it out why?

https://jsfiddle.net/8qdx4j9g/

```
    .toast {
    visibility: visible;
    min-width: 250px !important;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
    animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;} 
    to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
    to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;} 
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
```

Comment: You should use `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Comment: Yeah it fixed it. But as a new technology is it the best approach? What alternative could I use?

Comment: It looks as supported as animation themselves (no date on Mobile though) , so it might be fine. Maybe using only one animation might be better ( as the start and ends value are the same for the full cycle)